# How make Dialogflow generate a random number?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to create a bank chatbot. For creating a new bank account for the user I want it to generate a random number and make it display to the user. How to do it?

Comment: I have one question, you just need to display to user or you need to store into the variable and use it further in the same session ID.

Comment: As `Dhruv Rajkotia` mentioned, could you provide some overview of what you want to achieve? You just want to display some random number each time, or save it some database with some information about user (user ID, etc), reuse it, etc

Comment: @Dhruv Rajkotia  I want the random number to be displayed to the user. Each time the user requests, a new random number should be generated and be displayed. The random number should of 10 digits.

Comment: @PjoterS Each time the user requests, a new random number should be generated and be displayed. The random number should of 10 digits.

Comment: So the number may repeat itself and you don't want to store this number anywhere. You just want something like user write
- number 
and then chatbot response with 10 digits random number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two possibility to do that. Using inline editor(cloud functions) or seperate webhooks. But as you don't need to store the account number in the session parameters then I think cloud functions will help you the most here.

Here I have create a Account intent and mapped the generateRandom function with that intent.

**package.json**

```
{
   "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
   "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "private": true,
   "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
   "author": "Google Inc.",
   "engines": {
        "node": "10"
    },
    "scripts": {
         "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
         "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
     },
    "dependencies": {
          "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
          "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
          "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
          "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
          "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0",
          "uuid-int": "3.1.0"
        }
 }
```

**index.js**

```
  'use strict';

   const functions = require('firebase-functions');
   const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
   const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
   const UUID = require('uuid-int');

   process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

   exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

   function generateRandom() {
      const accountNumber =String(UUID(10).uuid()).slice(-10);
      agent.add(`Your account number is ` +accountNumber);
      console.log(accountNumber);
      // So here we haven't stored the account number in the parameter so we can use it for the same intent only. 
    }
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Account', generateRandom);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
 });
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Thanks